# Editing an initialized struct member using fstream C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am stuck in the code where I have initialized the struct member but I don't know how can I edit or delete it in a txt file.  (Is this possible?) Since I am making a "pc part shop" about processors and motherboards.Any tips are appreciated. Also sorry if my code is not clean, I am beginner.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<fstream>
    
    const int size = 5;
    
    struct Computer
    {
        string processor[size];
        string motherboard[size];
    };
    
    struct Prices
    {
        double proc_prices[size];
        double mboard_prices[size];
    };
    
    void display_proc(struct Computer comp, struct Prices price);
    
    int main(){
        int chosen_proc, chosen_moth;
        Computer computer = {
            {"1. Asus Prime A320M-K AMD AM4 uATX MotherBoard with LED lighting, DDR4 3200MHz, 32Gb/s M.2, HDMI, SATA 6Gb/s, USB 3.0","2. MSI H410M-A PRO LGA 1200 Supports 10th Gen Intel Core and Pentium Gold / Celeron processors"}, // processsor array init
            {"1. Intel Pentium Dual Core G2030 3.0Ghz 3MB Cache LGA1155 22nm Processor", "2. Intel Core i3-7100 Processor (3M Cache, 3.90 GHz)"} // motherboard array init 
        };
        Prices all_prices = {
            {2499, 5999},
            {2999, 3999}
        };
        system("Color 0A"); // this is just a design only i'm testing it
        
        ofstream proc1("processor.txt", ios::app);
        ofstream mother1("motherboard.txt", ios::app);

    cout <<"Choose your Processor!" << endl;
    if(proc1.is_open()){  
        display_proc(computer, all_prices);
        proc1.close();//file close  
    }  
    else{  
        cout<<"Error in file opening"<<endl;  
    } 
    cout <<"Enter a number: ";
    cin >> chosen_proc;


        }
void display_proc(struct Computer comp, struct Prices price)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << comp.processor[i] << "  "  << endl
         << "Price: Php"<< price.proc_prices[i] << endl;
         
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to delete text from a file. Nor is it possible to edit text in a file unless the new text is exactly the same length as the old text. The way to do what you want is to read the **whole** file into memory, make the edit in memory (which is easy) and then write the all the data back out to the file. Forget about trying to edit part of a file, operate on the whole file.

Comment: Note C++ learned may things from C. One of them is there isn't much point to always having to write `struct` when declaring a variable of a type that's a `struct`. Compiler knows darn well what `Computer` is (unless you're dumb enough to redefine it), so you can just write `Computer comp` and be done with it. Also look into references. Very handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not what you are asking about but really you are going to find this much easier if you make the following transformation to your code.

Instead of having two structs of arrays

```
struct Computer
{
    string processor[size];
    string motherboard[size];
};

struct Prices
{
    double proc_prices[size];
    double mboard_prices[size];
};

Computer computer = ...;
Prices all_prices = ...;
```

have an array of structs

```
struct Computer
{
    string processor;
    string motherboard;
    double proc_price;
    double mboard_price;
};

Computer computers[size] = ...;
```

This way all the information for one make of computer is held together in a single struct, instead of being scattered in multiple places. Your method can work, but you will find this way much easier to handle.